# How to access Excel data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am trying to access data from Excel in C#. Ideally I want to put the data into a list or a series collection. I was using this tutorial - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Excel-file-using-OLEDB-Data-Provider-in-C-Net.aspx.

It was very helpful but I think he missed out the data adapter part. Here is the code I got following his example.

```
        string connectionString = null;
        connectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = P:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SmartSheetAPI\\SmartSheetAPI\\bin\\Debug\\OUTPUT.xls; Extended Properties = 'excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;';";            

        //Establish Connection
        string dataSource = "P:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SmartSheetAPI\\SmartSheetAPI\\bin\\Debug\\OUTPUT.xls;";
        string excelConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + dataSource + " Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes'";
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Accessing Sheets
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        connExcel.Close();

        //access excel Sheets (tables in database)
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        da.Fill(dataset);
        connExcel.Close();
```

If you look at the bottom three lines you will notice he uses da.SelectCommand and da.Fill to fill the dataset. But I think this requires a dataadapter and he doesn't have that in his example. I have tried creating a dataadapter as below:

```
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

But I get an error stating: cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'.

I know it is working right up to the select statement. Can someone help me I basically just want to be able to access the information I am getting in the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `OleDBDataAdapter`, not `SqlDataAdapter`. So, do this:

```
OleDBDataAdapter da = new OleDBDataAdapter(cmdExcel);
da.Fill(dataset);
```

Excel is an OLEDB data source, and so the classes you should be using will be prefixed with `OleDb` in general, just like the ones for database connectivity and manipulation are prefixed with `Sql`.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing excel data  using Oledb connection is always a headache.You can try third party controls instead, like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/).Usage is very simple .You can try the following code after adding the control's reference to your project.

```
//Creating a file stream containing the Excel file to be opened
FileStream fstream = new FileStream("C:\\book1.xls", FileMode.Open);

//Instantiating a Workbook object
//Opening the Excel file through the file stream
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(fstream);

//Accessing the first worksheet in the Excel file
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

//Exporting the contents of 7 rows and 2 columns starting from 1st cell to DataTable
DataTable dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0, 7, 2, true);

//Binding the DataTable with DataGrid
dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;

//Closing the file stream to free all resources
fstream.Close();
```